# What syntax am I missing?

Tags: mariadb, mysql-error-1064

I am a completely new to `SQL` and I am follow a tutorial verbatim to try and create a new table in my first database.  However I am getting the following error.

```
USE menu;

CREATE TABLE Burgers
(
`Burger Number` TINYINT,
Burger VARCHAR(50),
Price DECIMAL(5,2),
Description VARCHAR(300),

);
```

Yields **SQL Error 1064**:

```
SQL Error (1064): You have an errror in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 8
```

I made sure to use commas to separate each column and used parenthesis to what I understand is the proper way to do so. I am not sure if version is relevant but I am using `version 10.5.8 of MariaDB`. Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text

Comment: (You really should just name that "burger number" column something like "ID", incidentally.)

Answer (score 2):

You have one comma too many.

```
    ...
    Description VARCHAR(300),
);
```

You need commas between each column, index, or constraint within the CREATE TABLE statement, *except* for the last one before the closing parenthesis.

It should be like this:

```
    ...
    Description VARCHAR(300)
);
```

General tip about syntax errors: They tell you exactly where to look for the problem, because it reports the place in your SQL statement where the syntax parser got confused.

In this case it reported:

> ...right syntax to use near ')' at line 8

This tells you the problem is at that point in the syntax. The `)` didn't belong there, because the syntax was expecting something else. Because commas separate columns, it was expecting another column definition following a comma.